# Dropped Nikon D50: auto focus not working

Tags: nikon, nikon-d50

I dropped my Nikon D50, thigh high on concrete. It doesn't auto focus anymore. It sounds like it's trying but motor stops almost immediately. I have since used the lens on another D50 and it works fine. It must be the camera. I wonder if it can be fixed? Any suggestions?

Comment: If it can be fixed, the only people who can do it will be Nikon or an authorised repair shop. Though given that the D50 is getting on a bit, it will probably cost more than the camera is worth.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I had a similar case just a different scenario with my camera body rolling off a small cliff. Does the camera hold sentimental value to you? If not i'd buy a new camera as even with repairs it may have a few glitches.

Answer (score 3):

If it can be fixed, the only people who can do it will be Nikon or an authorised repair shop. Though given that the D50 is getting on a bit, it will probably cost more than the camera is worth.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how bad the damage is. Ask a service center about the cost of fixing it. If it is cheap I suggest repairing and maybe use it for sometime and if it works well then fine. Else get a new one and you can keep the old one as a show piece reminding you from time to time ,the value of a neck strap. If the repair cost it too high(it probably will be as cost of repair parts are also high for such a model) just leave it. D50 is a very old model and you might even like the upgrade to a newer one.

DON'T try to repair it on your own.

JUST DON'T. You will end the remains of camera that can't be used for anything

Comment: As the question is quite old, I'm pretty sure he already fixed it somehow or got rid of the camera. However, I like your answer more than the accepted, so here you go +1.